# jQuery UI draggable to smaller droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am using this http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

But I have a problem dragging to a droppable that is smaller than the draggable.
It will not drop on the droppable, but on the top left of the droppable.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://yart.com.au/junk/draggableProblem.jpg))</sub>

Is there any way around this?

Here is the code, thanks.

```
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 500,
    appendTo: 'body',

    helper: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).removeClass("enlarge");
      $(ui.helper).addClass("thumbnail");
      $(this).hide();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).show();
      //$(this).addClass("enlarge");
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass("imageContainer")) {
        $(this).addClass("thumbnail");
      }
      else {
        $(this).addClass("enlarge");
      }
    },
    //cursorAt: { top: 30, left: 40 },
    delay: 100,
    refreshPositions: true
  });


  $('.imageContainer').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        "position": "relative",
        "left": "0px",
        "top": "0px"
      });
      if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        // ui.draggable.addClass("thumbnail");
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);
        $(this).removeClass("border");
      }
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("enlarge");
      ui.draggable.addClass("thumbnail");
      $(this).addClass("border");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      // ui.draggable.removeClass("zoomIn")
      $(this).removeClass("border");
    },

    tolerance: 'intersect'
  });
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail  {
  height:60px;
  margin-right:10px;
  width:80px;
  z-index:1;
}
.enlarge {
  border:5px solid white;
  height:145px;
  width:195px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your jquery code for the draggable and the droppable? I think I know but the answer isn't jumping into my mind.

Comment: I added the code, thanks drachenstern

Comment: Sorry that I failed to get back to this one, I'll look at it in a bit and see if I can help you out... -- Can you post the CSS for the enlarge and thumbnail? -- What happens if you leave the classes on ui.helper alone on the draggable? does it drop as expected (even though it's large?)

Comment: One other thought, then I'm back to work for a bit: have you tried turning on the tolerance values? like tolerance: 'intersect'

Comment: Thanks Drachenstern! I have added the CSS. Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by leaving the classes on ui.helper alone? Tolerance intersect is already on the droppable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 500,
    appendTo: 'body',

    helper: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
   /* $(ui.helper).removeClass("enlarge");
      $(ui.helper).addClass("thumbnail");  */
      $(this).hide();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).show();
      //$(this).addClass("enlarge");
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass("imageContainer")) {
        $(this).addClass("thumbnail");
      }
      else {
        $(this).addClass("enlarge");
      }
    },
    //cursorAt: { top: 30, left: 40 },
    delay: 100,
    refreshPositions: true
  });
```

Try replacing your code with this block above and see if it comes close to what you want. It may not be perfect yet, but let's see if we can tackle one change at a time. What I'm hoping to observe is that it drops approximately like it should.

Comment: Thanks, here is the report :)

http://yart.com.au/junk/draggableProblem2.jpg ("Box Here" is where I think the Droppable is)

Comment: Try " tolerance: 'pointer' " instead of " tolerance: 'intersect' " -- The previous code change confirmed my expectation of what's occurring.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you drachenstern!

Comment: Did you understand why that fixed it? I imagine you can revert the removal of the classes as well. I just wanted to make sure where the error was occurring. (also, will you upvote my answer since it helped? -- I don't know if this is bad protocol...)

Comment: Thanks, similar problem here, same fix :)