# Jquery - Drop event not occuring if size of 'draggable div' is greater than 'droppable div'

Tags: jquery, css, html, draggable, droppable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery UI draggable to smaller droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542137/jquery-ui-draggable-to-smaller-droppable)

I have a draggable div and a droppable div. The draggable div is greater in height and width than droppable div. So the drop event is not happening.

```
<div id='draggable' style="width:500px; height:500px;">
       ABCABC
</div>


<div id='droppable' style="width:100px; height:100px;">
       XYZXYZ
</div>


$('#droppable').droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ){
                        alert("Drop event occured");
          }
});
```

When I made dimension of draggable div smaller than dropable div, then drop event triggered successfully.

Please guide me on how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the `tolerance` option to `touch` in the droppable method

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({ tolerance: "touch" });
```

The default is `intersect`, which means your draggable div has to overlap the droppable div by 50%.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is change the `tolerance` of your droppable.

> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether a draggable is 'over' a droppable. Possible values: 'fit', 'intersect', 'pointer', 'touch'.

```
fit: draggable overlaps the droppable entirely
intersect: draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50%
pointer: mouse pointer overlaps the droppable
touch: draggable overlaps the droppable any amount
```

By default it is `intersect`, requiring 50% overlap.  Perhaps try `pointer`.